# Prove that $3^n+2$ is not a prime for all $n\ge 0$, $n$ is a whole number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, induction, examples-counterexamples

> Prove that $3^n+2$ is not a prime for all $n \geq 0$, $n$ is a whole number.

The only proof that I can think of (which is not exactly the right way), would be to put $n=0, n=1, \dots, n=5$, and at $n=5$ we get a number that's not prime. Hence we have proved that $3^n+2$ is not prime.

Comment: $3^{n+2}$ is correct?

Comment: sorry i meant (3^n)+2, not putting the brackets has been my mistake

Comment: What's the question? What are you trying to prove?

Comment: Please, use MathJax, type `$3^n+2$` to get $3^n+2$

Comment: Using Fermat's theorem, for prime $p$ you have $3^p+2\equiv 3+2 = 5\pmod p$. This suggests taking $p=5$.

Comment: @SammyBlack I need to prove or disprove that $3^n+2$ is not a prime, for all n>=0, preferably by induction, if possible, rather than brute forcing my way and substituting values of n until I get a non-prime value.

Comment: The scope of the negation in "is not a prime for all n" is ambiguous.

Comment: @user10354138 for n=3, f(3)=$3^3+2$,which is equal to 29(which is prime)

Comment: @BrianMoehring You can assume the question is to prove that the statement: $3^n+2$` is prime for all n>=0` is invalid.

Comment: for $n=4, 3^4 + 2 =83$ is prime

Comment: Pick any one of them for your contradiction -- $3^0+2=3, 3^1+2=5, 3^2+2=11, 3^3+2=29, 3^4+2=83$ are all primes, contradicting your proposition "$(\forall n\geq 0)(3^n+2 \text{ is not a prime})$".

Comment: @user10354138 LionHeart is there another way to do it, rather than just plugging in the values.

Comment: $5\mid 3^5+2$ , hence there is at least one non-negative integer $n$ for which $3^n+2$ is NOT prime which is already enough for the proof.

Comment: I interpreted the claim different than apparently the other users did. It is unlucky formulated. Do you mean "For every $n\ge 0$ , $3^n+2$ is not a prime" ? Or do you mean "It is not true that for every $n\ge 0$ , $3^n+2$ is a prime" ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(\Bbb Z/5 \Bbb Z)^{\ast}$ is cyclic of order $4$ so $\forall m \in \Bbb N~(3^{4m+1} \equiv 3 \pmod 5)$, which means $\forall m \in \Bbb N~(5 \mid (3^{4m+1}+2))$.  Thus, there are infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $3^n+2$ is composite.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the given statement it is sufficient to find a natural number $n\geq0$ such that $3^n+2$ is a prime number. Take $n=0$. Then $3^0+2=1+2=3$ is prime. Perhaps a more interesting result to prove could be to show that $3^n+2$ is prime for some $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$.